# How do I apply data filter to only the table range and not the whole row?

Tags: excel

I have got two adjacent tables. When I apply data filter on first table, it filters the whole row hiding rows from 2nd table as well. How do I restrict filter to only the first table range?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your direct question *How do I restrict filter to only the first table range?* the answer is - you can't.

Reading the comments it seems what you need is to display the filtered table data next to a chart and another table.  There is a little know tool in Excel that you can use to achieve this - the *Camera* Tool.  With this you can create a dynamic image of a range and place it where you want. The image updates when a filter is applied to the source range, without affecting the rows on the Dashboard sheet.

Screenshots to demonstrate:
Setup with tables on seperate sheets, and camera images beside chart on dashboard sheet
[image: setup]

With Filter applied to Table A 
[image: filtered]

The Camera tool is not on the Ribbon (Excel 2010) or the standard toolbars (Excel 2003).  You need to add it using Customisation. (Add to Qucik Access Toolbar in 2010 or Tools/Customisation Menu in 2003)

Comment: Does this work for slicers as well? Looks like it only works with pivot table or tables or cells.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you won't be able to do that. When you filter, it filters the entire row (something to think about would be how the row number would display if that weren't the case). You will need to restructure your setup if you wish to prevent that (not sure of your particular use case, so sorry I can't give a more specific suggestion).

Comment: is it possible to split worksheet so it only applies to first table

Comment: @user236215 What is your particular setup? And I guess more importantly, what is the overall objective?

Comment: My goal is to show a data series on the left. There is a small 3 row table on the right side. Finally a chart also on the right that plots data from the 2 tables. Applying filter screws up the 2nd table and the chart also. Interestingly, when I undo the filter, the chart is still screwed up. Basically I cannot even undo. The chart is just gone. I have to close the workbook and open it again. Just terrible..

Comment: I cannot imagine how filtering a table erases the series on chart and is not even restored when I undo the filter. Unbelievable.

Comment: @user236215 Is it feasible to put your three-row table above the rest of the data? It should prevent that issue (not a perfect solution, I agree). Also, it is expected behavior that the chart changes based on the filter (charts default to showing data from visible rows in the range), but odd that clearing the filter does not fix it (it works for me on a small sample set).

Comment: The chart is the bigger issue here. I must have the chart next to my time series for visualization and analysis. When I filter, it removes all series, and even when I undo, it does not restore. This is troublesome. This seems like a huge design flaw.

Comment: @user236215 When you filter are you trying to adjust the chart to reflect the filtered data? Or does the chart display stay constant?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, where i had a table I wanted to remain static - like a key, but wanted to filter the main table.

To get around this, I copied the static table, and pasted it as an image. This way, when you filter on the main table, the image remains where you have put it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround for this general issue that others may have mentioned (but I don't see here):

You can't *filter* just a range (e.g. a few columns in a spreadsheet), but you can *sort* just a range. And by sorting the range, then deleting some blocks of unwanted cells in the range, then sorting the range back to the original order, you can fake a filter.

A bit clunky, but easy for some jobs if you're careful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd query the table data and filter in the query editor.  That will actually resize the table relative to the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to move the table which you don't want to be affected by filtering, below the filtered table.
A second solution is to have the other table, which you don't want to be affected by filtering, in another sheet. To show both tables, the filtered one and the other one, a new window must be created and then split on screen both windows (so both tables) with View - Arrange all - Vertical/Horizontal.