# Freeze rows/ columns when data is filtered

Tags: excel, vba

I have columns A-H on my worksheet that contain data which ideally needs to stay there. Columns J-W contains data which needs to be filtered.

The issue I have is that when i filter anything, the data in A-H is filtered as the rows are removed - is there any way to stop this from happening and only filter rows starting from column J?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I apply data filter to only the table range and not the whole row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338122/how-do-i-apply-data-filter-to-only-the-table-range-and-not-the-whole-row)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Excel always filters the entire row. I'd suggest redesigning your workbook not to have tables side by side. If the data absolutely has to be visible on the same spreadsheet the workaround would be to put the not-filtered table in a separate sheet then insert a text box next to the filtered table and link the data to it.

Step 1: Click the Text Box button under Insert tab, and insert a textbox in your worksheet.

Step 2: While text box is selected put your cursor in the formula bar, type in = symbol and then click on the cell you want to link to, and finally press the Enter key

As text boxes aren't linked to cells it should remain displayed even after you filter it.